# Getting a 503 for the resources as well while setting up for a maintenance page in NGINX

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, maintenance-plan

I'm trying to set up a maintenance page for an application, hosted via NGINX web server.

Currently I have this set up.

```
    location ^~/maintenance/ {
       root /path/to/the/maintenance/maintenance.html;
    }
set $maintenance 0;
if (-f /path/to/the/maintenance/maintenance.enable) {
   set $maintenance 1;
}
if ($maintenance = 1) {   
root /path/to/the/maintenance/maintenance.html
rewrite ^/(.*) /maintenance/maintenance.html break;
}
```

I have explicit CSS file in maintenance/CSS and images in maintenance/CSS

The behaviour with this set up is the case file is also getting rendered as the HTML doc and images are also not accessible when maintenance.enable file is present.

Comment: Hi Emir. Excuse me for that, but it is unclear for me. What you're trying to achieve is that if `maintenance.enable` exists, redirect each request to `maintenance.html`, is it ?

Comment: Hi Philippe, Yes I'm trying to have an explicit maintenance mode setup without having to edit the config for the maintenance mode. If the maintenance.enable file is present I'm redirecting the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked out when I moved the location block to the bottom of the logic(if Statements).

Since there was no issue in the syntax or anything, but nginx was trying to see the location once the conditions were met, but it did not find a location to work on. Correct me if I'm wrong as I'm new to nginx, I would love to get some insights of this scenario.